# Multiple instance of same fragments inside a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have got some weird problem after implementing multiple instance(loaded dynamically depending on the data) of same fragment inside a Viewpager.
My fragment class consists of a listview which will be populated according to the data retrieved from the server, but every time i swipe page from one to another, the data inside a listview of the fragment is jumbled.
Here is the code. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

This the Fragment class where the Viewpager is present.

```
public class Menu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTab;
SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout;

private ArrayList<String> menu_names;
private ViewPager pager;

ActionBarActivity act;
public ArrayList<ArrayList<All_Data>> menus;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    mSlidingTab = (SlidingTabLayout) act.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tab);
    mSlidingTab.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mSlidingTab.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_text, 0);
    pager= (ViewPager) act.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mSlidingTab.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return android.R.color.transparent;
        }
    });
    mSlidingTab.bringToFront();
    menuUpdate();
}


class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Meals.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menu_names.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i) {
        return menu_names.get(i);
    }
}


private void menuUpdate(String result) {
    //menu_names= List Retrieved from server
    //menus= List Retrieved from server
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(act.getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mSlidingTab.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

Meals.java(Fragment class):

```
public class Meals extends Fragment {

    ActionBarActivity activity;
    int position = 0;


    static Meals newInstance(int page) {
        Meals fragmentFirst = new Meals();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", page);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.meals, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        position = getArguments().getInt("position");

        ArrayList<All_Data> mMeals;
        Fragment menu = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Menu");

        mMeals = ((Menu) menu).menus.valueAt(position);
        ListView mList = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.mainMenu1);
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());
        mList.addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_text, mList, false));
        mList.addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, mList, false));
        Menu_adapter adapter = new Menu_adapter(((Menu) menu), mMeals, activity);
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (ActionBarActivity) context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MyApplication.getInstance().trackScreenView("Startes Screen");
    }
}
```

meals.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f2f3"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#f1f2f3"
        android:dividerHeight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That will return the Menu fragment object that was created on the activity that has it.

Comment: i am using it refer to the menus object from that fragment.

Comment: Since you are instantiating the same fragment more than once, you need to make sure each instance knows it's own list or it will change every time the fragment is recreated.

Comment: Fragment will be knowing its list, as it is retrieved from the Arraylist which stores the lists of class object..

Comment: Every time the fragment is recreated onActivityCreated will run everything again and since your arraylist isn't static (and shouldn't be since you are instantiating that fragment multiple times) your values will be also updated